# Using "meilleure chose depuis le pain en tranches" to convey "best thing since sliced bread"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Googling about the British idiom "Best thing since sliced bread" I encounter the French expression "meilleure chose depuis le pain en tranches". Is it a proper French idiomatic expression? For instance something like the following would sound idiomatic to a French natif or not at all?

> J'utilise un service de livraison en ligne et c'est vraiment la meilleure chose depuis le pain en tranches. C'est tellement pratique et pas trop cher.

Comment: Là encore c'est une traduction mot à mot sans tenir compte du contexte culturel. La traduction ne consiste pas à faire du mot à mot mais à trouver un équivalent qui parle à la culture à laquelle on s'adresse. Vu ce que pense la majorité des français pour le « pain en tranches » (entre guillemets car un français ne comprend pas « pain en tranches » comme un  anglais *sliced bread*) il faut chercher ailleurs. On trouve dans les dictionnaires [p. ex](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/to-be-the-best-thing-since-sliced-bread), mais d'autres options sont possibles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(English summary below)

Non, une traduction littérale ne peut pas du tout marcher, en tout cas en France, et probablement dans la francophonie en général sauf peut-être au Canada. Il y a un référent culturel qui est fondamentalement différent. Le pain coupé en tranche et vendu dans des sachets plastiques, en France, ça existe, mais c'est du pain de mauvaise qualité qui sert à faire des toasts. (Un sandwich normal n'est pas fait avec du pain de ce type, mais avec de la baguette.) Ça ne peut pas du tout être utilisé dans un contexte laudatif. Le pain coupé en tranche, c'est plutôt une invention absurde, qui ne sert pas à grand-chose (couper du pain soi-même, ce n'est pas difficile). Si quelqu'un me dit que quelque chose est « la meilleure chose depuis le pain en tranches », je me dis soit que c'est une mauvaise traduction de l'anglais (parce que je parle suffisamment anglais), soit que c'est une invention qui ne sert à rien et que la formulation est ironique.

Il n'y a pas d'invention particulière qu'on considère comme remarquable. On peut dire que quelqu'un « n'a pas inventé le fil à couper le beurre » pour dire qu'il n'est pas très intelligent : le fil à couper le beurre est proverbialement une invention *facile*, mais cela ne dit rien sur son utilité. Cette expression a d'autres variantes, la plus courante étant « n'a pas inventé l'eau chaude ». Mais aucune de ces inventions ne convient pour parler d'utilité.

Ici un francophone utiliserait simplement un terme laudatif plus générique.

> J'utilise un service de livraison en ligne et c'est une invention géniale. C'est tellement pratique et pas trop cher.

À noter que si on veut dire qu'une invention est évidente après coup (ce qui n'est pas le sens de l'original anglais ici), on peut dire que c'est « [l'œuf de Christophe Colomb](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92uf_de_Colomb) » (ou « l'œuf de Colomb » ? moi je dis toujours ça avec « Christophe »).

---

No, this expression cannot be translated literally (except perhaps in Canada). It relies on a cultural reference which does not work. In most English-speaking countries, sliced bread has a positive image: it's considered to be a convenient thing, and it's the kind of bread that many people think of first when they hear the word “bread”. In France, sliced bread is low-quality bread that's good only for toasts. A normal sandwich is made with baguette, and baguette is the kind of bread that most people think of first. You can't use “sliced bread” in a laudative manner.

There's no invention that's considered proverbially *useful* in French. There are inventions that are proverbially *obvious*: “*le fil à couper le beurre*” (slicing wire for butter), “*l'eau chaude*” (hot water). For something that's obvious in retrospect, there's “*l'œuf de Christophe Colomb*” ([Columbus's egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_of_Columbus)). But none of these have the meaning that's sought here.

We'd just use a generic laudative term such as “*une invention géniale*” (no exact English equivalent: *génial* connotes both “very useful” and “worthy of a genius”).

Comment: Le pain vendu en France dans des sachet en plastique et coupé en tranche est du pain d'excellente qualité, pourvu qu'il soit choisi parmi les meilleurs, comme pour tous les produits.

Comment: @LPH Je parle de la perception culturelle. Du bon pain en France, c'est du pain frais, qui n'a pas d'additifs, et ne se garde pas longtemps. Ça n'a rien à voir avec les contrôles sanitaires. Le pain vendu en sachet a une connotation négative.

Comment: C'est admis, l'effet sur la santé peut ne pas être des meilleurs, mais alors il faut spécifier cela, comme du point de vue gout c 'est un pain qui a souvent la qualité supérieure de ne pas coller au gencives en amas glutineux, alors qu'assez souvent ce n'est pas le cas de la baguette ou de la flûte française. Rappelons aussi que c'est le seul pain utilisé au ÉUA depuis longtemps et que la Food and Health Administration ne s'en plaint pas.

Comment: Gilles &  @LPH  let's use the term [pain de tradition française](http://www.boulangerie.net/forums/bnweb/dt/additif.php) which is a label that anyone can identify so that we know what we are talking about. But I agree that my comment is totally irrelevant as was LPH's who started the conversation. Once again it shows my point that language cannot be dissociated from culture.

Comment: @Laure Actually, no. The point is indeed that language cannot be dissociated from culture. The word “*pain*” **alone** evokes the kind of bread that is not sold sliced and goes stale very fast if the soft part is exposed, and not the kind that has additives that makes it last for months and is sold in plastic wrappers. Whether it can legally be called “*pain de tradition française*” is irrelevant. For example see how far down you have to go to see pre-sliced bread [on a random supermarket site](https://www.carrefour.fr/s?sort=&q=pain).

Comment: @Gilles wrote  *Du bon pain en France, c'est du pain frais, qui n'a pas d'additifs, et ne se garde pas longtemps*. Well that's what is called *pain de tradition française* and what you were talking about. Only this label is some sort of guarantee (cheating can exist as consumers' associations have sometimes shown) that there are **no additives**. But you can be sure that all bread, whatever type (*baguettes, pain de campagne*, etc.) not carrying this label will have some additives. The Food  and Health Administration

Comment: The Food & Health Administration has very different standards from the ones we have in France, especially where additives in food are concerned.  - Maybe we should start [French Seasoned advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) - (joking) - !

Comment: A great answer, though it's worth noting that even in English the expression is more or less ironic – not that the praise is insincere, but that the comparison is funny. Even here in Canada where it's the usual format, everyone knows that sliced bread is nothing to write home about. (Or should I say "rien de quoi faire une lettre à ses parents"...)

Comment: @LukeSawczak *nothing to write home about* : « Il n'y a pas de quoi casser trois pattes à un canard » ou « Il n'y a pas de quoi fouetter un chat ». (Avertissement : je ne fais que signaler des expressions, je suis contre la torture des animaux.)

Answer (score 2):

Comme très justement observé par @Laure en commentaires dans l'OP, on ne pourra rien traduire justement sans tenir compte du contexte culturel.

Je souhaite en profiter pour tirer un coup de chapeau à un grand auteur et ajouter : Ni... des volontés humoristiques... :

Ainsi l'excellent Bob de Groot qui, dans *Léonard*, met souvent cette tournure dans la bouche de son héros (inventeur du XV<sup>e</sup> siècle) en prenant, pour référence, une invention que le lecteur sait... bien plus tardive.
Et, quand il n'y a pas nécessairement évidence, lui fait ajouter "*d'ailleurs il faudra que je l'invente"*...

Comment: Ça me fait penser aux objets du Catalogue d'objets introuvables (Carelman). Ça ne serait-il pas plus clair avec un « Je » ou autre sujet (que ... l'invente)?

Comment: @Laure : Bien vu! Merci pour ta relecture.

Comment: De rien, j'ai lu, mais bon, tu ne réponds pas à la question (je n'ai pas upvoté bien sûr !)

Answer (score 2):

L'expression "la meilleur chose/invention depuis le pain tranché/en tranche" est en usage au Québec dans le même sens. C'est peut-être un emprunt, mais comme il n'y a aucune expression française qui traduise cette formule assez percutante, je n'y vois aucun inconvénient.

L’exemple de LPH qui utilise le "bouton à quatre trou" est un fait un barbarisme combinant cette expression et "ne pas avoir inventé le bouton à quatre trou", équivalent québécois de "ne pas avoir inventé le fil à couper le beurre" (un ustensile qui n'a jamais vraiment été en usage au Québec).

Answer (score -2):

La page [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/the+best+thing+since+sliced+bread.html) sur cette phrase ne fournit rien qui corresponde en tant qu'expression coutumière. Il y est fait état d'une « réutilisation » de la phrase utilisant l'idée du fil à couper le beurre.

- Il/elle n'a pas inventé le fil à couper le beurre.

Cette phrase signifie que la personne concernée n'est pas très intelligente et sous-entend que l'invention est quelque chose d'assez ingénieux. Donc, on peut reprendre l'idée et dire ceci.

- … rien de mieux depuis l'invention du fil à couper le beurre.

Ce qui reste dans ce dictionnaire est limité à des phrases qui s'inspire de l'original anglais.

- … il ne s'est rien fait de mieux depuis le pain tranché.
- … c'est la meilleure chose qui soit arrivée depuis l'invention de la planche à pain.

On retrouve l'idée du fil à couper le beurre dans [Wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/the%20best%20thing%20since%20sliced%20bread) avec une addition qui est utilisée au Canada.

- la meilleure invention depuis le bouton à quatre trous.

On trouve aussi des contributions personnelles ([forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-best-thing-since-sliced-bread.269787/)).

- on n'a pas fait mieux depuis l'invention de la roue/poudre.

Comment: Je pense que dans cette histoire de fil à couper le beurre, l'implicite est plutôt qu'il s'agit d'une invention très simple et donc que si la personne ne l'a pas inventé c'est qu'elle n'est vraiment pas intelligente. Du coup je touve que ta réponse ne marche pas trop.

Comment: @Evpok C'est vrai, ce n'est pas aussi ingénieux que je le dis. J'enlève cette exagération. Je ne pense pas que l'idée du pain tout coupé soit d'un niveau d'ingéniosité bien différent.

Comment: Aucune de ces propositions n'a le sens voulu. Si je les entendais, je me demanderais ce que la personne a voulu dire.

Comment: @Gilles Quel est le sens voulu selon vous ?  Ces idées, en particulier celle du fil à couper le beurre, se retrouvent dans plusieurs sources concernées par la traduction de « best thing …» ; de plus, il s'agit bien d'une invention dans tous les cas.

Comment: Ce sont des inventions mais aucune n'a la bonne connotation. Tout ce que je vois, ce sont des gens qui ont essayé de traduire une invention par une invention. Mais le résultat n'est compréhensible que si on sait que c'est une traduction et qu'on rétablit l'original anglais.

Comment: @Gilles Il me semble que l'expression anglaise vise seulement à vanter une invention en la comparant à une invention connue qui représente à peu près la même difficulté de recherche ; en cela les traductions françaises, même si elles n'ont pas l'avantage de constituer une expression coutumière, sont adéquates puisqu'elles ont un sens complet, il n'y a rien d'idiomatique. Qu'est-ce qui manquerait ou qu'est-ce qu'il y aurait de plus dans l'anglais ?